# Node+Express+Jade: Only layout.jade is rendering

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I have a route defined as

```
server.get('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log('INDEX!');
    res.render('index.jade', {
        locals: {
            title: 'Your Page Title',
            description: 'Your Page Description',
            author: 'Your Name'
        }
    });
});
```

And `index.jade` is defined as:

```
div hello world!!
```

But what I visit `http://localhost:8081/` all I see is the layout, no "hello world!". I didn't even extend the layout in my view... why is this happening?

`INDEX!` *is* being rendered to my console, so I know it's hitting that route.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `.jade`:

```
res.render('index', {
    locals: {
        title: 'Your Page Title',
        description: 'Your Page Description',
        author: 'Your Name'
    }
});
```

Also make sure you have your view configuration set correctly:

```
server.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
server.set('view engine', 'jade');
```

Comment: I think the `.jade` extension is optional. The boilerplate I'm using came with that. Views are correct.

Comment: The jade extension is optional as long as you set the `view engine` to `jade`

Answer (score 1):

I needed to add

```
server.set("view options", { layout: false });
```

To tell `express` not to use the default layout automatically. I guess because my view didn't define the `content` block (used in my layout) none of my content was appearing; only the layout.